# Processing XACML policies in java

Tags: java, unmarshalling, xacml

I am actually working on a project that needs to parse the XACML policy file and detect the policies defined inside , to do so i've seen some of api but either they speak about how to build a request or how to parse the response (from the pdp ) , 
so i am asking if any one could help ( i know that i can do it using JAXB but i do not know wich information to retrieve ) 
Thaknk you for answering in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add more context to your question..? You can [sun-xacml](http://sunxacml.sourceforge.net/) to parse XACML policy files and figure out what's inside it..

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering , actually i solved the problem by using the OPENSaml2.2 api and it works fine for me .

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use more up-to-date XACML implementations.

Open-source implementations include Heras-AF, WS02, SICSACML, and enterprise XACML.

Vendor implementations include Oracle, Axiomatics, and IBM.

The Axiomatics implementation is the most up-to-date one. It supports XACML 2.0 and XACML 3.0.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and excuse me for taking all of this time to answer you , i found already another solution for this problem using OpenSAML2.1 which contain a good implemenetation of XACML1.0 and XACML2.0